# How to let inline block div which overflow put on the previous line

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to do like this↓↓
[image]

but the demo is this↓↓
[image]

When these inline-block divs overflow one rows, they would not drop down next row and put one the previous line.

```css
.store-card {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ed6c4d;
}

.store-change {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ed6c4d;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 4px 25px;
  color: #ed6c4d;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.store-active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ed6c4d;
}
```

```html
<div class="store-card">
  <div class="store-change store-active">
    <span>豆豉鸭</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>卤肉</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>板栗鸡</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>麻婆豆腐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>香菇炖鸡啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>可乐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>紫苏酱香鸭啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>鲜肉馄饨啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>玉米蒸饺啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>凉拌青瓜啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>烧骨粥啊</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to change it.
If only css more better.

**Important: this div is dynamic data, is not static.**

Comment: in your code nothing is happening.So it's hard to understand your problem

Comment: As the elements are rendered from top to bottom not bottom to top in a page, so it would not handled by CSS. But you can try using javascript/jquery with `position` and render every store value accordingly.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar i think agreen.but the data from php,is hurt to control.

Comment: @ShylaNie try my answer posted before sometime, which is made using `jquery`(needed to calculate positions of each store).

Comment: @Rohan Kumar Thanks!!(=￣ω￣=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get left and top positions of each store and make an array of objects for it. After that using loop assign `bottom` with `position:absolute` to each store like,

```js
function bottomToTop() {
  var poff = $('.store-card').position();
  var origHeight = $('.store-card').outerHeight();
  var objs = {
    left: [],
    bottom: []
  };
  $('.store-change').each(function() {
    var o = $(this).offset();
    //console.log(o,$(this).outerHeight());
    objs.left.push(o.left);
    objs.bottom.push(o.top === poff.top?0:o.top-8);
  });
  $('.store-change').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: objs.left[i],
      bottom: objs.bottom[i]
    });
  });
  $('.store-card').css({
    'top': origHeight
  });
}
$(function() {
  bottomToTop();
  $(window).resize(bottomToTop);
});
```

```css
.store-card {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ed6c4d;
  position: relative;
}

.store-change {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ed6c4d;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 4px 25px;
  color: #ed6c4d;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.store-active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ed6c4d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="store-card">
  <div class="store-change store-active">
    <span>豆豉鸭</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>卤肉</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>板栗鸡</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>麻婆豆腐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>香菇炖鸡啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>可乐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>紫苏酱香鸭啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>鲜肉馄饨啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>玉米蒸饺啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>凉拌青瓜啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>烧骨粥啊</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, I learnt something from this question, especially down to up menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the 5th store-change always needs to start on a new line, I would use flow left and clear the 5th element.

```css
.store-card {
  width: 100%;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ed6c4d; */
}

.store-change:nth-child(5) {
  clear:left;
}

.store-change {
  border: 1px solid #ed6c4d;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 4px 25px;
  color: #ed6c4d;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

.store-active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ed6c4d;
}
```

```html
<div class="store-card">
  <div class="store-change store-active">
    <span>豆豉鸭</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>卤肉</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>板栗鸡</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>麻婆豆腐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>香菇炖鸡啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>可乐啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>紫苏酱香鸭啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>鲜肉馄饨啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>玉米蒸饺啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>凉拌青瓜啊</span>
  </div>
  <div class="store-change">
    <span>烧骨粥啊</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/crkrbf9z/)

Comment: Ok. But it is always the same one? If it changes to the 4th or the 6th it would require a minor CSS change.

Comment: you might not understand what i want to say...maybe my description is not clear...please see the difference betweent the two pictures

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. In that case javascript will be required to detect the overflow and the same for the first line in case the screen size becomes too small. Complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gerards fine solution i would add a clearfix class or do something like this

```
.store-card:after {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  clear: both;
}
```

After that you can use your red border

Comment: please see the difference betweent the two pictures

Comment: yes I did it - it should be an addition to this answer from Gerard:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279231/6193316